# PyMODM get objects without _cls

Tags: python, mongodb, pymodm

I have a collection that was previously filled with documents without `_cls` field.

for example now I'm populating collection with these classes:

```
class SomeAnimal(MongoModel):
    ID = fields.CharField(primary_key=True, validators=[UUID])
    dob = fields.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        write_concern = WriteConcern(j=True)
        collection_name = COLLECTION_NAME


class Pet(Animal):
    name = fields.CharField(blank=True)
```

And `Pet.objects.all()` returns only documents added from this script (with `{'_cls':'Pet'}` property).

Is it possible to get these documents with Pymodm or this case breaks all sense of using ORM and it is better to switch to pymongo?

Answer (score 1):

From docs:
How does this work? For every model class that allows inheritance, pymodm creates another, hidden field called _cls that stores the class of the model that the document refers to. This way, models of different types can be collocated in the same collection while preserving type information.

What if we don’t want this _cls field to be stored in our documents? This is possible by declaring the model to be final, which means that it has to inherit directly from MongoModel and cannot be extended:

```
class PageTheme(MongoModel):
    theme_name = fields.CharField()
    background_color = fields.CharField()
    foreground_color = fields.CharField()

    class Meta:
        final = True
```